# Installing Cuda7.0 after removing cuda 7.5

Tags: apt, nvidia, python, dpkg, cuda

I was setting up to use google's shiny new library TensorFlow. So being excited I began the tensorFlow pip install. Noticing that I needed cuda I went to the Cuda website and downloaded the 7.5 deb and loaded it up.

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-28_amd64.deb
```

then I installed it.

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

And Finally I added the necessary lines to my bash.rc file.

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-7.5 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64 

PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
export PATH
```

Now the problem arises when I try to use tensor flow, pop open a python console,

```
 >>>import tensorflow as tf
```

Now here's the catch

```
 ImportError: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I need Cuda 7.0! So I install cuda7.5,

```
 apt-get remove --purge cuda
```

and download and load the the cuda7.0 deb cd to downloads and load that with

```
 sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

Unfortunately because I loaded the cuda7.5 deb apt-get install cuda installs cuda7.5 not cuda 7!

any Advice is appreciate.

**Nutshell**

How can I undo:

```
 sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is

```
sudo dpkg -r cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

It is the remove command.  The -r

If you want to learn more just do

```
man dpkg
```

You can also look at this stuff graphically with synaptic.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```